# Is there a specific algorithm for these kinds of problems?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

I came across a couple of similar problems where there are a couple of items in the set **e<sub>i</sub> = {w<sub>i</sub>,h<sub>i</sub>}** for `i=0..n`, you have to find the longest series such that **w<sub>m</sub> > w<sub>m+1</sub>** and **h<sub>m</sub> > h<sub>m+1</sub>** for each succesive value of `m`.
Does it sound familiar?
Can anyone point out a specific algorithm that may have dealt with similar problems?

Comment: [Longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) with various partial orders.

Comment: @Per this isn't exactly longest common subsequence, because e1=(3,4),e2=(2,5) has no relation (not <,>,=) so you can't use binary search on it. Or any other well known comparison based method.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to build a directed acyclic graph that has a node for each ei and an edge from ei to ej iff ej > ei (in the sense you state above). Then [find the longest path in this DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Weighted_directed_acyclic_graphs).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the longest increasing subsequence, so [patience sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patience_sorting) is probably the way to go.

When you implement this, you'll need to write your own Comparator method that says `e_i < e_j` if and only if `w_i < w_j` and `h_i < h_j`. The fact that you have a partial order instead of a total order does not change the algorithm.

Comment: The patience sorting works for total ordered sequence not input sequence as OP said. in fact you don't have [totality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation) in this sequence because you don't have a<=b or b<=a in all cases for example a =(4,3), b=(5,2) non of them is bigger or equal. in fact there is no relation between them.

Comment: Patience sorting works for partial orders. It's often called Topological sorting in that case.

Comment: Would you show me your reference? It uses binary search, so it should use total ordered sequence, or may be you know something else? Topological sorting is what Irit offered and in this case is O(V+E) not O(n log n) like patience algorithm.